# postgresql partman.run_maintenance_proc() getting issue with partition_default containing 9999-12-31

Tags: postgresql

I have faced the issues while running `partman.run_maintenance_proc()` after migrating the partitioned table into PARTMAN because partition_default containing special value in partition key column such as efftv_to_dt = '9999-12-31 00:00:00' ....

My partitioned table:

```
Partition key: RANGE (efftv_to_dt)

test.acct_p2024_03 FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-03-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-04-01 00:00:00'),
test.acct_p2024_04 FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-04-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-05-01 00:00:00'),
test.acct_p2024_05 FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-05-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-06-01 00:00:00'),
test.acct_default DEFAULT
```

My partman configuration:
premake = 4

When I ran `CALL partman.run_maintenance_proc();`

It took long time for trying to create number of child partitions till date 9999-12 that caused out of memory error finally

My question is how to execute partman.run_maintenance_proc with partition default table not empty

I tried to create a special partition that covers data of 9999-12-31 as below instead of storing in partition_default as a workaround solution but I am not sure any other special values coming in the future which would be causing the same issue

```
alter table test.acct attach partition test.acct_p9999_12
for values from ('9999-12-31 00:00:00') to ('10000-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but why do you need 9999-12-31 ? Is that some default value for an unknown data somewhere in the future? If so, a NULL is imho a much better solution.

Comment: Hi @FrankHeikens, it is a special value to represent an active record in database so we couldn't use NULL as replacement

Comment: Hi @FrankHeikens which partition would be used to store NULL values in partition key column as you mentioned. I think it would not be default partition because it will cause same issue with partman.run_maintenance_proc()